# Proplem in connecting to database Ms Sql server by "JAVA" JDBC

Tags: java

I have this code to select a Course in database:

```
String sql="Select * From Class where ClassID='"+k+"' ";
try {

    st=this.cnn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(sql);
 }
```

==> I don't know how to take result of "Class" entity returning in the Statement: `st.executeQuery(sql)`. It works but returning type is a number? How can I recieve "Class" datatype!?

Comment: Note that this is vulnerable to SQL Injection. You should [use prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: Read a JDBC tutorial on how to work with `ResultSets`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should loop through `ResultSet` (rs.next()) and initial coressponding class and set value for it.